# Reboot loop - "normal" fixes didn't work - how to recover data?

Tags: boot-loop, data-recovery

My Nexus 5 is in a reboot loop and all the normal "fixes" (e.g., going into recovery mode and clearing the caches, etc.) don't work. It looks like it is a hardware problem as the phone is even rebooting instantly when going into recovery mode (I can't even select an option from the recovery menu as it disappears too fast).

I've since bought a new phone but realized that I have important data on my old internal memory, and yes, I don't have a backup (shame on me).

How to obtain data from the internal memory of the phone? Is there any way? Connecting the phone via USB didn't help me ... the computer does not have enough time to detect a device as it immediately goes into a reboot loop again.

Edit: I think my power button may be defect, because I don't even have to start my phone to go into a reboot loop, it does it all by itself.

Comment: Raw approach, if your bootloader is unlocked: boot a custom recovery (e.g. `fastboot boot twrp.img`) and access your data from there?

Comment: My bootloader is not unlocked.

Comment: Oh. Then this is no viable as unlocking the bootloader usually implicates a factory reset, sorry.